# get node and subnode text value in simpleXML

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml, domxpath

I need to find a way to extact the text content of a node + subnode using simpleXML.

Here is a dummy exemple:

```
<library>
    <book>
        <title>I love <i>apple pie</i></title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>I love <i>chocolate</i></title>
    </book>
</library>
```

Considering that that XML is stored in a $xml variable, here is my php:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($sxml->xpath('//book') as $book){
    //echo $book->title returns "I love"
    //var_dump ($book->xpath('string(title)') returns empty array.
    // What I want : "I love apple pie" (on the first iteration of the foreach) "I love chocolate" (on the second iteration of the foreach)

    }
```

Am I missing something here ? Strangely enough, simpleXML seems to recognize the xpath ('string') function, but it doesn't seems to evaluate it. Is this a bug? is there any work around? 
I have started to explore a solution with DOMDocument and DOMXpath::query, but it seems that the document goes back to the root element, which is not the behaviour I am wanting in the foreach...

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$book->title` is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). You could pass that to [dom_import_simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) and get the [nodeValue](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue):

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($sxml->xpath('//book') as $book){
    echo dom_import_simplexml($book->title)->nodeValue . "<br>";
    // or use
    // echo strip_tags($book->title->asXml()) . "<br>";
}
```

That will give you:

```
I love apple pie
I love chocolate
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XfUQe)

Comment: Yes ! That works ! Thanks a lot ! By the way, do you know why xpath function string() is not evaluated ? What about the other xpath function ?

Comment: I think that is because the `var_dump($book->title);` looks like `object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
  ["i"]=>
  string(9) "apple pie"
}
`. You could also get the xml from asXml and use strip_tags to remove the html `echo strip_tags($book->title->asXml());`

Comment: Well... that's a bit of a desapointment ! using xpath is so easy and perfomant, too bad that not all of it is well-managed by the library... But anyway thanks a lot !!!